# Airflow example dags runs fine and logs shows up on UI however any custom dags always fail and logs do not show up on UI

Tags: airflow

I am new to airflow. I installed airflow using the docker image in separate containers as show below. I am able to run the example dags successfully and can see the logs on the airflow UI however any custom dags always fail and do not show any log on airflow UI. I can see the logs for example dags in the 'base_log_folder' path however nothing for custom dags. I cannot make out why custom dags fail without knowing what the root cause. Any help is greatly appreciated.

CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                              COMMAND                  CREATED        STATUS       PORTS                                       NAMES
b02acfa97aa4   bitnami/airflow-worker:latest      "/opt/bitnami/script…"   24 hours ago   Up 5 hours   8793/tcp                                    airflow-worker
6d3248484abf   bitnami/airflow-scheduler:latest   "/opt/bitnami/script…"   24 hours ago   Up 5 hours                                               airflow-scheduler
a77104ebab02   bitnami/airflow:latest             "/opt/bitnami/script…"   24 hours ago   Up 5 hours   0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, :::8080->8080/tcp   airflow
e9240395fc51   bitnami/redis:latest               "/opt/bitnami/script…"   24 hours ago   Up 5 hours   6379/tcp                                    redis
e1aad6ab1ba1   bitnami/postgresql:latest          "/opt/bitnami/script…"   24 hours ago   Up 5 hours   5432/tcp                                    postgresql

Comment: do you see any error in the ui ? if yes whats the error ? if not, it might be that your custom dags not in the right dag folder

Comment: If you see my original post, I can see the custom dag on UI which means the dag is in the correct dag folder. There is no error log shown on the UI for the custom dag. It is not clear why the custom dag failed since there is no log.

Comment: Have you configured `base_log_folder` in your airflow.cfg file or Environment Variable `AIRFLOW__LOGGING__BASE_LOG_FOLDER`?

Comment: Yes, airflow.cfg has base_log_folder=/opt/bitnami/airflow/logs.

Comment: Do you import any modules (not from airflow)? Can u share one of the dags?